# Axios in React Native not calling backend server

Tags: react-native, axios

I'm building a react native app for sign up and login. The backend works well. I checked with Postman. But the frontend doesn't call the server for the post request.

This is the Register.js

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import  Axios  from 'axios';
import {
    StyleSheet,
    SafeAreaView,
    View,
    Text,
    TouchableOpacity,
    TextInput,
} from 'react-native';
import { ScrollView } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';

export default function Register({ navigation }) {
    
    const [nom, setNom] = useState();
    const [prenom, setPrenom] = useState();
    const [username, setUsername] = useState();
    const [matricule, setMatricule] = useState();
    const [specialite, setSpecialite] = useState();
    const [email, setEmail] = useState();
    const [password, setPassword] = useState();

function save() {
    console.log({
        "matricule": matricule,
        "nom": nom,
        "prenom": prenom,
        "username": username,
        "specialite": specialite,
        "email": email,
        "password": password

    })
        Axios.post("http://192.168.1.1:8080/api/save",{
            'matricule': matricule,
            'nom': nom,
            'prenom': prenom,
            'username': username,
            'specialite': specialite,
            'email': email,
            'password': password
        },
        {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Accept': 'application/json'
            }
        }
    )
    .then(res => console.log(res.data))
    alert("User Registation Successfully");
    navigation.replace('Login');
}
```

I see the alert and it navigates to another screen, and returns the data i entered correctly, but it's like it ignores the post request.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You're invoking an asynchronous operation and then, before any result has been received, immediately notifying the user that the operation succeeded (which you don't know) and immediately navigating away (which I expect could very well just abandon the asynchronous operation).

Perform these tasks *in response to* the asynchronous operation, not while it's still executing:

```
.then(res => {
  console.log(res.data);
  alert("User Registation Successfully");
  navigation.replace('Login');
});
```

Comment: Despite doing that, it still ignores the post request and navigates to the other screen.

Comment: @ikram: Is the `console.log` statement invoked?  What does it log to the console?  How specifically are you observing that "it ignores the post request"?

Comment: this is what is in the log :  {"email": "e", "matricule": "2", "nom": "r", "password": "R", "prenom": "d", "specialite": "r", "username": "c"} . For your second question, I see nothing on my backend ide

Comment: @ikram: If the AJAX operation is successfully completing and is producing a result then why do you assume "it ignores it"?  What's the actual observable problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: Nothing is inserted into the database, I have tested in Postman and the api works just fine. That's why I made that assumption

Comment: @ikram: There's no code here which inserts anything into a database.  Now is a good time for you to start doing some debugging to narrow down the exact problem.  In your debugging, observe the result of each individual operation.  For example, does the object being posted to the server contain the data you expect?  What is the full contents of `res` in the AJAX response callback?  If these things match expectations then the next step is to debug server-side code.  Continue in this process until you identify which operation isn't doing what you expect.